# Python how eval a string of list with precision to decimal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, decimal

I have a string which is list like this

```
list_str = '[148654.08425925925, 148656.99994212962, 148658.08229166668, 148661.0020601852]'
```

then I use eval() to convert it to real list object in Python

```
print eval(list_str)
```

However, the output is rounded which I don't want

```
0 = {float} 148654.084259
1 = {float} 148656.999942
2 = {float} 148658.082292
3 = {float} 148661.00206
```

How could I make it keep the values as in String (decimal with precision) ?

*I need to use eval() because it will use other operation on this list as well*

Comment: Never name a variable things like  `list`, etc... Now you cannot call `list(..)` after that statement.

Comment: Furthermore are we talking python-2.x or python-3.x?

Comment: it is an example to get you the idea, thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you want to use this with `numpy` or would the python `Decimal` type suffice?

Comment: I want to use with the python decimal to make it as simple as possible, @tdelaney

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem probably 2.x as the `print` is not parenthesised.

Comment: 3.x keeps all of the decimals

Comment: can I do it on 2.7 ? Druck ? thanks

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, what's the point of speculating? Why "probably 2.x"? Lots of people use Python 3. Guessing something like that isn't helpful; let the OP answer.

Comment: Is the numpy tag relevant?

Comment: Just to point out the obvious: a (potentially) very easy fix to your problem is using Python 3.x instead of Python 2.7. In Python 3.5, your code produces the result that you require.

Answer (score 1):

`floats` are represented by binary fractions and there is a loss of precision when converting to and from the dotted decimal representation you are using ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)). The python [`decimal` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) implements decimal floating point arithmetic and doesn't have that limitation.

You can't use `eval` to break up the list because those values will evaluate to floats, but you can use the regex package to extract the floats and build the list from there.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> import re
>>> list_str = '[148654.08425925925, 148656.99994212962, 148658.08229166668, 148661.0020601852]'
>>> items = [decimal.Decimal(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+\.?\d*', list_str)]
>>> items
[Decimal('148654.08425925925'), Decimal('148656.99994212962'), Decimal('148658.08229166668'), Decimal('148661.0020601852')]
>>>
```

Comment: seem like I don't have other idea, thanks for your useful comment.

Answer (score 1):

While there can be loss of precision in floating point, there is no loss of precision here, given that it looks like the string was generated from a Python list of floats to begin with.  Note that `ast.literal_eval` is recommended over `eval`, however:

```
>>> list_str = '[148654.08425925925, 148656.99994212962, 148658.08229166668, 148661.0020601852]'
>>> import ast
>>> L = ast.literal_eval(list_str)
>>> L
[148654.08425925925, 148656.99994212962, 148658.08229166668, 148661.0020601852]
```

Note the above exactly matches the original string.  However, printing individual floats as opposed to the whole list defaults to six digits after the decimal, so if you want more precision, specify it:

```
>>> for f in L:
...     print '{:.11f}'.format(f)
...     
148654.08425925925
148656.99994212962
148658.08229166668
148661.00206018519
```

I also recommend looking into the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) modules for saving the list in the first place to avoid using `eval` or even `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Decimal in python

```
from decimal import *
mlist = '[148654.08425925925, 148656.99994212962, 148658.08229166668, 148661.0020601852]'
mlisttrim = mlist[1:-1]
l = []
for i in mlisttrim.split(', '):
    l.append(Decimal(i))
print l
```

Comment: I need to use eval() because it will use other operation on this list as well.

Comment: @BằngRikimaru, never use `eval()` unless you're _very_ sure you need to. It can run arbitrary code. You almost never need it. Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast.literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) instead.

Comment: @Chris yeah, it can change anything, I have same idea, but I would need to solve this problem with the decimal first, thanks.